# Symfony2 URLs 404 in apache2 after rebuild of VM

Tags: php, apache, symfony

We have the following system:

- Symfony 2
- runs on Ubuntu LTS 12.04
- served by apache2 2.2.22
- Jenkins builds project at least once a day
- Vagrant & Puppet are used to create the runtime environment from scratch every time

The problem: Suddenly the Symfony URLs were not served anymore.

While `curl localhost:8081/app_dev.php` worked like a charm (of course it yielded an error message from Symfony, but it *was* Symfony that answered), all real symfony URLs stopped working:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ curl localhost:8081/app_dev.php/_test/data/class/clean
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /app_dev.php/_test/data/class/clean was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8081</address>
</body></html>
```

Usually, Apache should give that url to `app_dev.php` and be done with it; `app.php` URLs behaved exactly the same way.

Neither Apache config, vhosts nor `.htaccess` did change between working and failed runs. Symfony routing was unchanged as well.

What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, `libapache2-mod-php5filter` was installed instead of `libapache2-mod-php` during puppet provisioning. We did not explicitly state in our manifest that `libapache2-mod-php5` should be installed, instead it was installed as dependency of `php5`.

Basically `libapache2-mod-php5filter` is the same module as `libapache2-mod-php5`, just that it is supporting filters:

```
 Unless you specifically need filter-module support, you most likely
 should instead install libapache2-mod-php5.
```

The two packages are mutually exclusive (at least in debian/ubuntu)

I am not sure how that package came to be installed instead of `libapache2-mod-php5`, but an install of `libapache2-mod-php5` solved the problem (as that automatically uninstalled `libapache2-mod-php5filter`).

We put that package install into our puppet files, and the problem is gone.